# What functions includes a Library?

Tags: c, linux, linker, makefile

Is there a manual or a method available to find out which file `libXX.so` contains the functions and so on from the header YYY.h ?

For example:

I include a header foo.h with the function foofunk() inside.
But the linker says  undefined reference to foofunk().

Note:

I want to use a Makefile for the build and link process. (GCC)
And my sources are in C, but that should be unimportant.

Comment: If the creator of the library cares about naming convention and good practice, then `<foo.h>` declares functions defined in `libfoo.so`. If he doesn't, you shouldn't use that library anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 sry I don't understand what you are meaning

Comment: @Manfred read again, I mistakenly hit Enter

Comment: For well behaved libraries, you might be interested in http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump).

```
objdump -T library.so | grep ' Base ' | grep ' function_name$'
```

Now loop over shared libraries you suspect of defining a given function and check each of them using objdump.

```
for f in /usr/lib/lib*.so; do \
  objdump -T $f | grep ' Base ' | grep -q ' function_name$' && echo $f && break
done
```

Remove `break` if you want to continue searching despite having found the library you're looking for.

In case of static libraries substitute `-T` with `-t` and get rid of one of `grep`s.

```
objdump -t library.a | grep ' function_name$'
```

Comment: `:/usr/lib$ for f in /usr/lib/lib*.so; do   objdump -T $f | grep -q printf && echo $f && break; done
/usr/lib/libasprintf.so`  Is that example output meaning, that printf is in libasprintf.so ?

Comment: And what if I suppose that the function is in a libXX`.a` ?

Comment: I've revised the answer again. Does it solve the problem now?